# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constrains - such constrains not in the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making a music app, but while incoming call comes, when I accept the call Xcode showing the following error.

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
     (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x137692b60 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13769b8e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x137578ba0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13752b850 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13769b8e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x137578ba0 )>"
```

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

but there no such UIInputWindowController or UIOnputSetContainerView in storyboard. Please help I am new to xcode. this is not a duplicate question I am not able to figure out from same like question. This error is not affecting the app, but warning showing in debugging area

The conflicting constrains are hilighted in the image

[click for screenshot](http://s29.postimg.org/jldvux9rr/image.png)

Comment: What are the views that you have added in the view controller that shows these warnings? Have you configured your views programmatically or using storyboards?

Comment: Using storyboards. One UIView, and inside the view one UIButton. There is no warning but when I accept the incoming phone call. While app is running....the debugging window show this error..but app is working

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/jldvux9rr/image.png this i think the conflicting constrains

Comment: There should be only one of those two constraints installed

Comment: I am not able to delete that constraints since it created by xcode, it shows only in xcode debug view hierarchy.  Any idea to delete that through code

Comment: If you have added all constraints through storyboard you should be able to see it there in the view hierarchy. Delete it from there.

Comment: I removed all constraints from the storyboard..bu stil shows this problem..  Plz check the attched pic. That constraints i am not able to see in the storyboard. But it whos while debugging view hierarchy method

Comment: It looks like those constraints  problem comes from the phone dialer. I have exactly the same issue. Whenever I get back to my app from a call constraints that I don't have could not be satisfied. A bug? Maybe.

Comment: With the same error I submitted the app to appstore. Appstore approved it. So I think its a bug may be. This error comes only when the call comes.